# Netbeans RCP Platform - use module as Library in other module

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Consider **Module_Suite "A**" contains two **Module "B" and "C**" .
And **"B" is dependent on "C" API** .

So is there a way to use Module "C" API in "B" module as library ?

Comment: As this seems to be a circular dependency between **B** and **C**, I have a feeling that in this case the module partitioning is not right. Either: 1) **B** and **C** should be in the same module, or 2) the part that defines the API in module **C** should be a separate module.

Comment: I propose to reformulate your question